# User Defined Variables in spark - org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to add user defined variables that can be used inside filter and map functions in spark, currently I am getting an error while trying to do that.

EDIT : I am running this code on zeppelin notebook so I dont have to create a seperate class.

My code is somewhat like :

```
val some_value = "qwerty"
val some_other_value = "x.y.z"

data.filter(r => r.getString("a.b.c").equals(some_value))
.map(r => (r.getString(some_other_value)))
```

Please note that, here "data" is an RDD containing JSONs

I am getting the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:341)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:340)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.filter(RDD.scala:340)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$fa17825793f04f8d2edd8765c45e2a6c$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:202)......
at $print(<console>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpretInput(SparkInterpreter.java:747)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:711)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:704)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ClassloaderInterpreter.interpret(ClassloaderInterpreter.java:57)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:93)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:312)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:171)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkContext, value: org.apache.spark.SparkContext@7f166a30)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: c, type: class org.apache.spark.SparkContext)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@65b97194)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@5e9afdf2)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@1d72f175)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@7b44290b)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@2fd0142d)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@1812605b)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@40020ce9)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC@3db9c1c)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC@6968a929)
    - field (class: $iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC, $iwC@1e8d42e6)
    - field (class: $line25.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iwC)
    - object (class $line25.$read, $line25.$read@6b4256a)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $VAL5449, type: class $line25.$read)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@7d6cf781)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@f4d2716)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@d8c3a34)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@7bc0d5a5)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@74ef7040)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@7e55be5d)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC@2f59915e)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC@36faa9d0)
    - field (class: $iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC, $iwC@54f2aef7)
    - field (class: $line385.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iwC)
    - object (class $line385.$read, $line385.$read@3d8590f3)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$fa17825793f04f8d2edd8765c45e2a6c$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $VAL5516, type: class $line385.$read)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$fa17825793f04f8d2edd8765c45e2a6c$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$fa17825793f04f8d2edd8765c45e2a6c$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@419dfc19)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$fa17825793f04f8d2edd8765c45e2a6c$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $outer, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$fa17825793f04f8d2edd8765c45e2a6c$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$fa17825793f04f8d2edd8765c45e2a6c$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$fa17825793f04f8d2edd8765c45e2a6c$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@6e994c6d)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$2e9cf4ebd66898e1aa2d2fdd9497ea7$$$$C$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$fa17825793f04f8d2edd8765c45e2a6c$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$2e9cf4ebd66898e1aa2d2fdd9497ea7$$$$C$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1, <function1>)
    at 

    org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
        ... 123 more
```

EDIT 2 : Finally I got the solution, just wrap the whole code as a scala function and pass the parameters.

```
val some_value = "qwerty"
val some_other_value = "x.y.z"

def func (value_1 : String, value_2 : String) : RDD[String] = {
val d = data.filter(r => r.getString("a.b.c").equals(value_2))
.map(r => (r.getString(value_2)))
return d
}

val new_data = func(some_value, some_other_value)
```

Another method is to use functions for complete operations inside the closure.

```
def myFilter(e: String) = (r: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord) => r.getString("a.b.c").equals(e)
def myGenerator(f: String) = (r: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord) => r.getString(f)

val p = data.filter (myFilter(x)).map(myGenerator(y))
```

Comment: Please [edit] to show the full class and stacktrace

Comment: The trouble usually with Spark is that it tries to serialize everything in the function graph. Is `some_value` or `some_other_value` defined in a class which is not serializable? Or extends/implements something which is not serializable?

Comment: @Saket - I am defining them as standalone variables and not inside any class, so I am not sure if thats the problem, but I am new to spark and still learning the tricks. I ran the above code as is. Is there any way to serialize a variable?

Comment: @cricket_007 : edited with full error message containing the stack trace

Comment: Are you running this from Spark shell? You should be able to run the query if you inline the vars into the lambda itself.

Comment: Your stacktrace points to SparkContext, it is being referred to by one of your blocks in the notebook. Is all the code from your notebook pasted here?

Comment: Hi I updated my answer with edit which uses case class. case class are by default serializable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable` exception, it means that you use a reference to an instance of a non-serializable class inside a transformation.

Beware of closures using fields/methods of outer 
object (these will reference the whole object)

For ex :

```
NotSerializable notSerializable = new NotSerializable();
JavaRDD<String> rdd = sc.textFile("/tmp/myfile");
rdd.map(s -> notSerializable.doSomething(s)).collect();
```

[Here are some ideas to fix this error:](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/javaionotserializableexception.html)

1. Serializable the class
2. Declare the instance only within the lambda function passed in map.
3. Make the NotSerializable object as a static and create it once per machine.
4. Call `rdd.forEachPartition` and create the `NotSerializable` object in there like this:

`rdd.forEachPartition(iter -> {
  NotSerializable notSerializable = new NotSerializable();`

`// ...Now process iterator`

`});`

Also, look at [Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException when calling function outside closure only on classes not objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592811/task-not-serializable-java-io-notserializableexception-when-calling-function-ou)

> Tip : Can use jvm parameter to see detailed info about serialization
>
> **-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true** in **SPARK_JAVA_OPTS**

- ### SerializationDebugger :

  [SPARK-5307](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5307) introduced SerializationDebugger and Spark 1.3.0 is the first version to use it. It adds serialization path to a `NotSerializableException`. When a `NotSerializableException` is encountered, the debugger visits the object graph to find the path towards the object that cannot be serialized, and constructs information to help user to find the object.For ex :

  `Serialization stack:
      - object not serializable (class: testing, value: testing@2dfe2f00)
      - field (class: testing$$anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class testing)
      - object (class testing$$anonfun$1, <function1>)`

## EDIT

I'm directly trying to address problem here...

> Since we are going to run our Spark application on JVM, we have a
>   requirement that in order to serialize an object your class should
>   explicitly extend special `Serializable` interface. In Scala when you
>   are declaring a case class it automatically extends the `Serializable`
>   interface.

## 1.`case class` approach :

`object Test extends App {
  case class MyInputForMapAndFilter(somevalue: String, someothervalue: String)
val some_value = "qwerty"
val some_other_value = "x.y.z"
val myInputForMapAndFilter = MyInputForMapAndFilter(some_value,some_other_value)
 data.filter(r =>      r.getString("a.b.c").equals(myInputForMapAndFilter.somevalue))
    .map(r => (r.getString(myInputForMapAndFilter.someothervalue)))
}`

Case class in scala is by default `serializable`

## 2. Another approach you can try : you can declare `val` as ***`transient`***

```
@transient val some_value = "qwerty"
@transient val some_other_value = "x.y.z"
data.filter(r => r.getString("a.b.c").equals(some_value))
  .map(r => (r.getString(some_other_value)))
```

please try this ans let me know output... pls be proactive to ask more questions/ problems

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed post and suggestions. I tried your recommendation, but I am still getting a serialization error. I implemented exactly the way you described!

Comment: you implemented in the same way  as above code snippet?

Comment: are you using java serialization of kyro ?

Comment: Yes, I ran the code in the same way as above, I am using Zeppelin notebook to run these commands, so will I have to use java serialization of kyro seperately?

Comment: Ok can you wrap all the variables in to one object and pass as filter ?

Comment: Hi Please see my updated answer and try. change : enclosed in an object

Comment: updated answer : change is - declared variables as `transient`

Comment: transient solution didn't work either, but I have found the solution finally, have updated it above. But thanks a lot for the tips :)

Comment: initially I suggested your updated method 2 i.e like this `rdd.forEachPartition(iter -> { NotSerializable notSerializable = new NotSerializable(); // ...Now process iterator `

Comment: calling within closure I thought it was not working either thats where I suggested `case` ,  `transient` solutions

Comment: For your information [case solution](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/demystifying-spark-serialisation-error) and [Transient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206108/spark-1-6-1-task-not-serializable-when-evaluating-a-classifier-on-a-dataframe)  are inspired from the links

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use a broadcast variable which you can then fetch in map and reduce functions.

For example to create the broadcast variable do:

```
val broadcastString = sc.broadcast("my string")
```

And in your map and reduce functions you can get the broadcasted string using:

```
val myStr = broadcastString.value
```

See here for more: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables

Comment: I am still getting the same error :


`bString_1: org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast[String] = Broadcast(55)
bString_2: org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast[String] = Broadcast(56)
bString_a: String = WebSessionStartEvent
bString_b: String = body.customProperties.Queue.value
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
 at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
 at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
 at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean....`

Comment: sorry for the jumbled error message, im not able to format it.